# values not get displayed in jsp while integated with struts and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts-1

PropertyShow.java (ActionForm)

```
 public class PropertyShow extends ActionForm{
            private int id;
            private String pname;
            private String paddress;
            private int price;
            private int pcontact;
            // GETTERS AND SETTERS...
    }
```

PropertyAction.java (Action)

```
public class PropertyAction extends Action{
    PropertyDao pdao;
    public ActionForward List(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws Exception {
        
            PropertyAdd property = new PropertyAdd();
            PropertyService propertyImpl = new PropertyService();
            PropertyShow propertyform=(PropertyShow)form;

            //save it
            List<PropertyAdd> propertylist =  new ArrayList<PropertyAdd>();

            propertylist = propertyImpl.showAllproperty();
            request.setAttribute("propertylist",propertylist);

            return mapping.findForward("show");
          } 
    }
```

PropertyAdd.java

```
public class PropertyAdd implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private String pname;
    private String paddress;
    private int price;
    private int pcontact;
    // GETTERS AND SETTERS...
}
```

PropertyDao.java

```
public interface PropertyDao {
        public List<PropertyAdd> showAllproperty();
}
```

PropertyService.java

```
public List<PropertyAdd> showAllproperty() {
        List<PropertyAdd> propertylist = new ArrayList<PropertyAdd>();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("From PropertyAdd");
        propertylist  = query.list();      
        return propertylist;       
    }
```

view.jsp

```
 All Property: 
    <br> 
    <%
       List prolist = (List)session.getAttribute("propertylist");
       request.setAttribute("propertylist", prolist);
    %>

    <logic:iterate name="prolist" id="propertylistId">
        <p>
       <bean:write name="propertylistId" property="id"/>,
         <bean:write name="propertylistId" property="pname"/>,
         <bean:write name="propertylistId" property="paddress"/>,
         <bean:write name="propertylistId" property="price"/>,
        <bean:write name="propertylistId" property="pcontact"/>
      </p>
    </logic:iterate>
```

Hibernate Mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.montran.pojo.PropertyAdd" table="propertydetail">
     <id name="id" type="int" column="id"></id>
     <property name="pname" column="pname" type="string" />
     <property name="paddress" column="paddress" type="string" />
     <property name="price" column="price" type="int" />
     <property name="pcontact" column="pcontact" type="int" />
   </class> 
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

I was working on Struts1, Hibernate I was trying to get the data from database, but it was not get displayed in the JSP page but the query was created by Hibernate.

I don't know where is the error, maybe in integration part goes wrong and can someone help me on this.

Comment: In the action you set a request attribute. In the JSP you get a session attribute.

Comment: thank you for your response, changed it but same as before

Comment: changed it as request.getAttribute("propertylist"),but it shows error like javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean: "propertylist" in any scope